# PDF editable field names for C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm writing a C# program that edits PDFs. I'm looking for a list of PDF field names. 
From what I understand, PDF's have field names for chunks of the document (like footer, header, etc). I may be wrong on this, but I've read a fair bit that suggests this.

I can't seem to find a list of standard field names. I'm wondering if anyone can direct me to one. Or, at the least, provide me with the field-name for the footer of a PDF.

If I'm wrong on all of this, please let me know, and if you can, provide me with a link to better understand editing a PDF with C#.

Thanks

Comment: *I may be wrong on this, but I've read a fair bit that suggests this.* - i wonder which sources suggest that.

Answer (score 1):

> From what I understand, PDF's have field names for chunks of the
>   document (like footer, header, etc).

This is completely wrong.

> I can't seem to find a list of standard field names.

There is no such list. There are two types of interactive forms: AcroForm technology and the XML Forms Architecture.

- When using AcroForm technology, the fields are defined using PDF dictionaries and represented as widget annotations. The names of the fields can be chosen by the person creating the form: "customer", "address", "country",...
- When using XFA, the form is described using XML and you can use any XSD to create the fields (you choose your own tags / field names).

> provide me with a link to better understand editing a PDF with C#.

Please read the intro of [chapter 6 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf). PDF is **not** a document editing format.

**My assumption:** you are confusing Tagged PDF with interactive forms. When you talk about fields, everybody thinks of a form. From the context of your question, I think you are talking about Tagged PDF.

Most of the PDFs don't know anything about the structure. You can create a PDF of which the content can be interpreted as a table by the naked eye, but when a computer program looks at this table, it will only see lines and parts of words and sentences. PDF only cares about presenting the data, not about the structure of the data. This is the default.

In the context of some standards (such as PDF/UA and PDF/A Level A), you can introduce a structure. The result is a Tagged PDF. In this structure, there is a predefined set of elements for this structure, so that a computer program parsing the document can identify titles, paragraphs, table rows, table cells, etc... These elements are described in ISO-32000-1.

Headers and footer are not part of this structure. They are defined artifacts, because they are not part of the real content. For instance: a PDF/UA file of a novel can be read out loud, and you don't want the running header to be read because it's not part of the story.

Note that the names of these structure elements can also be chosen freely, but they are always mapped to one of the standard names (using the RoleMap entry).

I don't know the context of your question, but you should really read and understand ISO-32000-1 to get a full understanding of what you're trying to achieve. Right now, it sounds as if you're trying to do something that is impossible.

Comment: …or could it be that the OP has read about the PFN convention? (old stuff, but one never knows). In this case, we have a convention on how to name fields used for entering and displaying person-related information (name, address, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Field names are identifiers for form fields such as text fields and check boxes. I suspect you confuse fields with PDF tags. These do mark layout elements such as headings, footers, etc.

Here you can find their names:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7cd8.w.html